# MongoDb how to find previous and next item in a list

Tags: mongodb, nosql

suppose I have a collection with a following structure

```
{
'_id': 'some id',
'items': [item1, item2, ..., itemN]
}
....
```

can you help me, how I can find previous and next item if I know 'some id' and itemK

Of course I can just return all items and later parse them on server side.
But I think that there should be some solution

Comment: do you know itemK's index in the array ? because you can extract just a chunk of an array using an offset and a limit, but in your case you need to know the offset.

Answer (score 0):

You can [selectively return individual fields](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimization#Optimization-Optimization#3%3aSelectonlyrelevantfields) but I can't see how you could return individual elements from an array in a field, and certainly not using a query based on relative positions within that array.

Is the items field so large that you need to return less than the whole field?

Comment: no it is not large. I just thought that if there is a simple way of doing this, I should use it